# Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' For Brave Browser Nighty Version

Tags: brave

I just installed the Linux Mint 21 x86_64
kernal version -5.15.0-67-generic on my computer and still don’t understand anything about it. I tried to install brave-browser (Nightly Channel Installation). I installed on this website https://brave.com/linux/#nightly-channel-installation. I get this error.

> Text Error: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Brave Browser Error doesn't support architecture i386

[image]

Brave Browser Nighty version installation errors

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 23):

I was having the same warning. After some digging, I just found a solution here:

https://community.brave.com/t/solved-linux-deb-install-gives-error-when-you-apt-update-a-repository/464626/3

I have the browser already installed, so, i just edited existing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list` file, adding this architecture parameter `arch=amd64`, as follows:

`deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main`

And it solved!

Comment: Thanks, this was annoying and worked for me.